# Using Python to create new point location based on various azimuth and distances

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, point, line, azimuth

I have a feature class with thousands of points. In the same table with these point locations, I have two additional fields. One for azimuth, and one for a length (or distance) to move along that azimuth in order to create a new point location. I am looking for guidance on a python script that would accomplish this task?

```
table example 
x             y          length_fornew_point       azimuth 
400460.99 135836.76       5150.04                    55.41 
.... ....
```

Ultimately the script would run through my table, look at the existing coordinates and create a new end point at corresponding specified distance/azimuth in the table.

These two coordinates would then be used to create a new two point polyline.

Comment: Do you have access to the arcpy site-package?

Comment: Hmmmm. How would I determine that?  I'm using ArcGis 10.2 if that helps.  Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

ArcGIS has a tool to do just that called [Bearing Distance To Line (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000ts000000).

[image]

---

The syntax is as follows (from ESRI help):

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Local variables
input_table = r"c:\workspace\LOBtraffic.dbf"
output_fc = r"c:\workspace\SOPA.gdb\lob_traf001"

#BearingDistanceToLine
arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management(input_table, output_fc, "X", "Y", 
"NAUTICAL_MILES", "azim", "DEGREES", "GEODESIC","recnum")
```